# R complains about permissions when installing librarys. Where is R instaling packages?

Tags: r, installation

I am updating bioclite as an ordinary user, from inside R. I want R to update Biooclite in my personal library folder. I get a permission error. 
It doens't make sense since I have read/write permissions here.

How can I see where R is trying to install my librarys?

Comment: @Pascal thanks, I did that.  Where does it install, to the first?

Comment: @nsn yes it does. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `install.packages` there is an argument `lib` that controls where the packages are installed. By default it picks the first element of `.libPaths()`, see `?install.packages`:

> lib
>   character vector giving the library directories where to install the packages. Recycled as needed. If missing, defaults to the first element of .libPaths().

Comment: Is that also true for bioconductur? because the recomended method to install

islibrary(BiocInstaller)
biocValid()

I guess in background it calls install.packages, but maybe with a different location

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with BiocInstaller, but the help page for biocLite show that extra arguments will be passed to `install.packages`, so I would assume that it is true as well for bioconductor.